# Groovy - Shell Scripting - Unable to Communicate back n forth

Tags: java, bash, macos, shell, groovy

I'm very new to Groovy and trying to write a shell script that let me automate command line tasks.

Here is manual way.
I open terminal, use a command, which dont response right away but after some time, and then that command ask few questions which i answer y/n etc and then i get the final results.

Now i want to write a groovy shell script, that let me use a ProcessBuilder and then send one command, get output, and based on output write a second command and repeat this until process is complete.

I tried writing following script, but what happens is that im able to trigger first command but it doesnt wait for me to provide the input and goes ahead.

Please advise what change should i make in my code to WAIT for it to take input from my code AFTER i send first_command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

String workingDir = System.console().readLine 'Working Directory?';
workingDir = workingDir.trim();

if (!workingDir?.trim()) {
  workingDir = "/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Automation/test";
}

println "Your working directory is $workingDir";

Boolean isDone = false;
Boolean canMove = false;

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
processBuilder.directory(new File(workingDir));
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process proc = processBuilder.start();
Scanner scannr = new Scanner(proc.getInputStream());

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      while(true){
        while (scannr.hasNextLine()){
          println scannr.nextLine();
        }
        if(isDone){
          break; 
        }
      }
    }
}.start();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (isDone == false){
          if(canMove == false){
            canMove = true;

            // Write a few commands to the program.
            writer.println("first_command");
            writer.flush();
          }
        }

        if(isDone){
          writer.close();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of waitXXX functions in groovy extension for `java.lang.Process` class

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html

sample implementation if output of the process is not large:

```
Process p = "cmd /c dir c:\\".execute() //you can use BrocessBuilder here
def txt = p.with{
    def output = new StringWriter()
    def error = new StringWriter()
    //wait for process ended and catch stderr and stdout 
    it.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
    //check there is no error
    assert error.toString().size()==0: "$error"
    //assert it.exitValue()==0 //we can do check with error code
    //return stdout from closure 
    return output.toString()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,

I used ProcessBuilder because i "assumed" that UNLIKE "command".execute, ProcessBuilder can be used to run multiple Conditional commands in same started process. Which means using Execute is not something i want and waitForProecessOutput documentation says that "Finally, the input, output and error streams are closed.". I dont want them to close, i want to read the output like u did in output.ToString() and then send second command based on output to the same openned/started Process. 

Can i achieve this?

Comment: in any case new process spawned. after process spawned you can write to its input stream the output from the previous process. for example check the [leftShift](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)) method: `nextProc <<  prevOutput`

Comment: im afraid this w'dnt solve my problem, because the next command is not a command but answer to first command, for example when i start process with a command, that command ask few questions like a wizard with yes no and then links to website , then download that link, and finally proccess it and return result. Which means i need "Expect" framework like functionality.